# What does a domain register do? (e.g namecheap)

Tags: server, dns, isp

I have a basic understanding of how domains work, and would like to fill in some gaps.

Lets say you make a server request for `google.com` how do you get the `IP Address`?

> Do you request your `ISP`, with a domain for an IP, that request the global `DNS` that requests your domain register?

Basically is this what happens?

```
client asks ISP what is IP for "google.com"?
ISP asks Global DNS what is IP for "google.com"?
Global DNS asks namecheap what is IP for "google.com"?
returns IP back up stack to client
```

**or**

> Do you just send a http request packet with domain and your ISP just handles it? If so how?

**and**

> What do domain registers like `godaddy` and `namecheap` really do?

I would love some resources and knowledge to be pushed my way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at the wiki page for DNS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System ? Also I think this should be asked on another stackexchange site as it is not a programming question.